# Find all solutions to the system of equations $a+b+c=1$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$, $a^4+b^4+c^4=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Find all solutions to the system of equations $$a+b+c=1$$ $$a^2+b^2+c^2=2$$ $$a^4+b^4+c^4=3$$

By squaring the first equation and substituting value of $a+b+c$ we get $\sum ab=-\frac{1}{2}$

From first equation we get:  $a+b=1-c$, on squaring both sides and substituting $a^2+b^2=1+c^2-2c-2ab$ in $2$nd equation we get $2c^2-2c-2ab-1=0$

How to proceed after this?

Comment: how about Newton's polynomial?

Comment: Yes, use Newton identities like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162199/polynomial-system).

Comment: A mechanical approach is to use a Gröbner basis. It will show that $(2a+1)(4a^2-6a+1)$ is in the ideal generated by these equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From squaring the first two equations we get
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac=1$$
$$a^4+b^4+c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2=4$$
We then can get that
$$ab+bc+ac=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2=\frac{1}{2}$$
Squaring the first of these 2 equations gives
$$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+2abc(a+b+c)=\frac{1}{4}$$
So,
$$2abc(a+b+c)=-\frac{1}{4}$$
$$abc=-\frac{1}{8}$$
This means that $a,b,c$ are roots of the polynomial
$$x^3-x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{8}=0$$
$$8x^3-8x^2-4x+1=0$$
Substitute $y=2x$,
$$y^3-2y^2-2y+1=0$$
$$(y+1)(y^2-y+1)-2y(y+1)=0$$
$$(y+1)(y^2-3y+1)=0$$
$$y=-1,\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{4}$$
So $a,b,c$ are some permutation of those $3$ roots.