# Solving a set of equations

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, real-numbers

Well, I am trying to solve the following system of equations for $\left(\text{a},\text{b},\text{c}\right)$:

$$
\begin{align*}\begin{cases}
\text{a}+\text{b}+\text{c}&=\alpha_1\\
\\
\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2+\text{c}^2&=\alpha_2\\
\\
\text{a}^4+\text{b}^4+\text{c}^4&=\alpha_3
\end{cases}\end{align*}
\tag1
$$

---

**My work**, I did the following working out:

If we square the first equation we get:

$$\left(\underbrace{\text{a}+\text{b}+\text{c}}_{=\space\alpha_1}\right)^2=\underbrace{\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2+\text{c}^2}_{=\space\alpha_2}+2\left(\text{a}\left(\text{b}+\text{c}\right)+\text{b}\text{c}\right)\tag2$$

Squaring the second equation gives:

$$\left(\underbrace{\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2+\text{c}^2}_{=\space\alpha_2}\right)^2=\underbrace{\text{a}^4+\text{b}^4+\text{c}^4}_{=\space\alpha_3}+2\left(\text{a}^2\left(\text{b}^2+\text{c}^2\right)+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{c}^2\right)\tag3$$

This leads to:

$$\alpha_1^2=\alpha_2+2\left(\text{a}\left(\text{b}+\text{c}\right)+\text{b}\text{c}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space2\left(\text{a}\left(\text{b}+\text{c}\right)+\text{b}\text{c}\right)=\alpha_1^2-\alpha_2\tag4$$
$$\alpha_2^2=\alpha_3+2\left(\text{a}^2\left(\text{b}^2+\text{c}^2\right)+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{c}^2\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space2\left(\text{a}^2\left(\text{b}^2+\text{c}^2\right)+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{c}^2\right)=\alpha_2^2-\alpha_3\tag5$$

Squaring equation $(4)$, gives:

$$\left(2\left(\text{a}\left(\text{b}+\text{c}\right)+\text{b}\text{c}\right)\right)^2=2\cdot\underbrace{2\left(\text{a}^2\left(\text{b}^2+\text{c}^2\right)+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{c}^2\right)}_{=\space\alpha_2^2-\alpha_3}+8\text{abc}\left(\underbrace{\text{a}+\text{b}+\text{c}}_{=\space\alpha_1}\right)\tag6$$

So, we can see that:

$$\left(\alpha_1^2-\alpha_2\right)^2=2\left(\alpha_2^2-\alpha_3\right)+8\text{abc}\cdot\alpha_1\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{abc}=\frac{\left(\alpha_1^2-\alpha_2\right)^2-2\left(\alpha_2^2-\alpha_3\right)}{8\alpha_1}\tag7$$

> And from this point on I am stuck.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359545/solve-xyz-1-x2y2z2-35-x3y3z3-97). One can always solve this by using Newton identities. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350998/find-all-solutions-to-the-system-of-equations-abc-1-a2b2c2-2-a4b?noredirect=1&lq=1), two hours ago.

Comment: From what you have done so far, you can write down a cubic equation, using Vieta's formulas, whose roots are $a, b, c$, but solving this in terms of $\alpha_1$ etc would be very messy